# Android: Download Manager resume issue

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am trying to download file using [Android Download Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html). As per docs:

> The download manager will conduct the download in the background, taking care of HTTP interactions and retrying downloads after failures or across connectivity changes and system reboots.

But, download manager never resumes download, after network connection is restored(At least, in my case). I even tried with setting the request header, using [addRequestHeader()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#addRequestHeader%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). But nothing worked. My code is as follows:

```
Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(BASE_URL));
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI
            | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
    request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
    request.setTitle("Aarti Sangrah.zip");
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Aarti Sangrah.zip");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        request.setNotificationVisibility(Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    } else {
        request.setShowRunningNotification(true);
    }
    if (isResuming) {
        request.addRequestHeader("Range", "bytes="
                + file.length());
    }
    enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
```

In the docs, I couldn't found any method for resuming downloads. Also, I have a BroadcastReceiver for monitoring network changes.